# How can I ensure that certain partitions of an RDD are always processed by the same Spark workers?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have to periodically process large batches of items in Spark.

Items are partitioned by a region key.

For processing an item, a large (many GB) in-memory database has to be loaded by the spark worker. Each region has a separate database. So each item requires exactly one regional database for processing.

All regional databases do not fit into the memory of one physical node at the same time. Therefore, I would like to distribute those regional databases among the workers.

They should be loaded only once on worker startup.

I think, for this to work, I have to ensure that partitions are always processed by the same worker nodes.

Are there any guarantees that this is the case? What would I have to do to achieve this?

Comment: https://acadgild.com/blog/partitioning-in-spark  Gives you the basics. Why RDD? Your term item is a little unclear. In any event you need to ensure that a region fits in on a node or further sub-divide to avoid OOM errors. Do you have some code to share or do you ask in general?

Comment: The title is a little odd. On start-up reading from disk you get some form of partitioning. You can then ensure by repartitioning that stuff with the same key(s), note the s, go to the same Executor on a Worker.A Worker has many Executors potentially.